# How to show the arrows of orbit when browser in on small resolution?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm working with a project which using the Zurb Foundation.

I have a problem now, how to display the arrows when the browser is on small resolution ?

It's always disappear when the screen size is small than breakpoint.

I would like to use the directlyNavigation even the view became small.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly not the most elegant solution (in an ideal world you would find and edit the source of this behavior instead of overruling it), but for a simple fix add this to your css or add to existing media queries in foundation.css, around line 1052:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {       
   .orbit-wrapper .slider-nav {  
       display: block !important; 
    }
}
```

Foundation Build: 3.5.2

Orbit Version: 1.4.0